# using variable extracted from selector

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use list elements to toggle between corresponding panels, I also want to do this using variables, just so I can orient myself with their use better. Here is my html and code below. I am tring to extract the i from the the "icon" id clicked, and use that i to open a corresponding "panel" id, with the attached i afterward. Any help would be appreciated! thanks!

html

```
<div id="icon0" class="icon">
                    <a href=""><img src="Images/film_icon.png"/></a>
                    </div>
<div id="icon1" class="icon">
                    <a href=""><img src="Images/film_icon.png"/></a>
                    </div>
<div id="icon2" class="icon">
                    <a href=""><img src="Images/film_icon.png"/></a>
                    </div>
<div id="icon3" class="icon">
                    <a href=""><img src="Images/film_icon.png"/></a>
                    </div>
```

html panels:

```
<div id="panel0" class="panel">0000</div>
                    <div id="panel1" class="panel">1111</div>
                    <div id="panel2" class="panel">2222</div>
                    <div id="panel3" class="panel">3333</div>
```

Jquery

```
for(var i=0; i<4; i++){
        $('#icon'+i).click( function() {  
        $('#panel'+i).fadeOut(400);
        return false;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   var iconPrefix = "icon";
   var panelPrefix = "panel";
   $("[id^='"+iconPrefix +"']").each(
    function(index, Element){
      $("#"+iconPrefix +index).click(function(event){
        $("#"+panelPrefix +index).fadeToggle(400);
      });
    }
   );
});
</script>
```

Comment: the jQuery .live() and .delegate() functions are worth looking at once you get the hang of this way to register events.

Answer (score 0):

Ok collect all your icons in an object, first, then whenever one is clicked get the index and trigger the fade on the corresponding panel:

```
var $icons  = $(".icons");
$icons.each(function() {
  $(this).click(function(evt) {
    var thisIndex = parseInt($(this).index());
    $("#panel"+thisIndex).fadeToggle(4000);
  });
});
```